# Getting an object to travel at or near light speed by adding velocities

Tags: speed-of-light, relativity, faster-than-light, rotational-kinematics

Firstly I'll just give a brief example of where my query came from. I was watching the episode of Futurama where Bender meets God after being fired from the planet express ships torpedo tube. The crew can't catch him because they were going top speed when he was fired meaning he's going much faster.

From this, I started to think a lot about moving objects utilising the speed of the object they're moving from and my thoughts eventually arrived at this.
If you have a motor on a table attached to a large disc, then you attached another motor and independent power supply to the top of the disc, and then attached that to another smaller disc with their centres aligned.

If you switch on the first motor and spin the first disc, they entire structure would move as one, but if you then remotely switched on the second motor spinning the smaller disc in the same direction, the smaller disc would be spinning faster.

An example of this principle I used to explain it to my friends is the idea of shooting a gun forward from a train moving at the speed of a bullet(http://science.howstuffworks.com/question456.htm)

My question is, could this effect be used to make an object travel/spin at or near the speed of light, perhaps through using several of these spinning discs on top of each other?
Thoughts?

Comment: That's the principle of a multi-stage rocket. Because of the relativistic addition of velocities it can't be used to reach the speed of light, either.